# Two similar types - how to make function for them?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I create a function that takes two similar types and at the same time returns them?

My example:

```js
   type First = {
        name: string,
        address: string,  
    }
    
    type Second = {
        name: string,
        email: string,
    }
    
    type Third = First | Second;
    
    function addSuffix(payload: Third): Third {
        payload.name += "suffix";
        return payload;
    }
    
    const a: First = {
        "name": "John",
        "address": "London",
    }
    
    const b: Second = {
        "name": "Alice",
        "email": "alice@alice.com"
    }
    
    function doA(payload: First): First {
        // some operations
        return addSuffix(payload);
    }
    
    function doB(payload: Second): Second {
        // some operations
        return addSuffix(payload);
    }
    
    doA(a);
    doB(b);
```

It's not working because of:

> Type 'Third' is not assignable to type 'First'. Property 'address' is
> missing in type 'Second' but required in type 'First'.

How can I change the addSuffix function to make it work? In other OOP language programming, I would use interfaces (interface with name property), but how to do it in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the function signature of `addSuffix` doesn't express the fact that it will always return the same type you pass in. This means that `doA` and `doB` can't be sure that it will return the type they're expecting.

> In other OOP language programming I would use interfaces (interface with name property), but how to do it in TypeScript?

Luckily, TypeScript also has interfaces:

```js
interface Nameable {
    name: string;
}

function addSuffix<T extends Nameable>(payload: T): T {
    payload.name += "suffix";
    return payload;
}
```

You don't have to manually implement `Nameable` for `First` and `Second`, as it is implied by the fact they both have `name` fields.

It's also worth noting that you can also use a type alias instead of an interface to achieve the same thing, just with slightly different syntax:

```
type Nameable = {
    name: string
}

function addSuffix<T extends Nameable>(payload: T): T {
    payload.name += "suffix";
    return payload;
}
```

Or you can even inline it:

```
function addSuffix<T extends { name: string }>(payload: T): T {
    payload.name += "suffix";
    return payload;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use an intersection type :

`type Third = First & Second;`

This way the **third** type return by the **addSuffix** method will be assignable to the **first** or **second** type you want since it contains the necessary properties.

Another cleaner solution would be to use an interface that the type can extend from :

```
interface INamed {
    name: string,
}

type Second = INamed & {
    email: string,
}


function addSuffix<T extends INamed>(payload: T): T {
  ...
```

Docs : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types

Comment: An intersection type wouldn't work here unfortunately - that would make `addSuffix` expect an object with `name`, `email` *and* `address` fields.